# Update multiple tables in a single query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multiple-tables

I have three query and I would like to have a single one. These is my query:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET a='' WHERE id=3;
UPDATE tab2 SET b='' WHERE id=9;
UPDATE tab3 SET c='' WHERE id=5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
UPDATE tab1, tab2, tab3
SET tab1.a = '', tab2.b = '',tab3.c = ''
WHERE tab1.id = 3 AND tab2.id = 9 AND tab3.id = 5;
```

**UPDATE:**

As per mentioned by OP, *the code not working for **Mysql 5.5**, below code added*

```
UPDATE tab1 a 
  INNER JOIN tab2 b ON (a.id = b.id)
  INNER JOIN tab3 c ON (a.id = c.id)
SET tab1.a = '', tab2.b = '', tab3.c = ''
WHERE a.id = 3 AND tab2.id = 9 AND tab3.id = 5;
```

Comment: @FrancescoG.,make sure you do used `Aliases` of every table with there respective Column names as;  **tab1.a** ,**tab2.b**, **tab3.c**

Comment: ...  work perfectly for mysql 5.6 but not for mysql 5.5! Any suggest?