# Update multiple tables in one SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I've done some research and figured out that it's not possible to do through one query, but instead could for example be done through a transaction. But I can't get the SQL query to work properly. If I use the statements one by one they work all good.

What should I do?

The goal is to update two tables with information from one form.

```
$query = "

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE projects

SET

projects.project_name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_name'])."',

projects.project_group = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_group'])."',

projects.project_notes = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_notes'])."',

projects.project_created = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_created'])."',

projects.project_start = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_start'])."',

projects.project_delivery  = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_delivery'])."',

projects.project_orderdetails = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_orderdetails'])."',

projects.project_owner = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_owner'])."'

where projects.project_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."';

INSERT INTO hours

hours.userhours_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_owner'])."',

hours.projecthours_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."',

hours.user_hours = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['user_hours'])."'

where projects.project_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."';

COMMIT;

";
```

Comment: @Scuzzy I've done some joins also but since one is update and the other is insert will it still work?

Comment: Sorry, Deleted my comment as It wasn't accurate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139831 looks interesting

Comment: No worries :) I've looked at that one before without success but will try to study it again and see what my error might be

Comment: got the table aliases or full table names in play?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to run them one by one and both works perfect but not combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mysqli` has methods for working with transactions, for example http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php.

Code can be:

```
$mysqli->begin_tansaction();
$mysqli->query('query1');
$mysqli->query('query2');
$mysqli->commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, went for two querys and executed as you wrote with my statements. All good for now :)